# How can i detect key combinations in Windows python3+?

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I am trying to program something that detects when a key combination is pressed and calls a certain function. So i need the program to detect something like ctrl+v when pressed and do something, but it seems like the program does not recognize ctrl+v together, but it does when i am only testing for 1 key:

```
COMBINATION = [
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='v')}
]
```

In this code, if i remove 1 of the 2 the program seems to detect the key, but if they're togeter it does not.
This is what i'm using to detect the keys:

```
def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATION]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in comb) for comb in COMBINATION):
            execute()
```

the `execute()` function never gets executed if both parameters are placed in `COMBINATION` but if there's only one it seems like it does work.
I am using pynput for keys pressed and a listener that listens to all key pressed:

```
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so there's a super simple library called `keyboard`

Install it with `pip install keyboard`

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+v'):
   # Call your function
```

I hope that I helped you.

Comment: How can i use that with my listener?
My program waits for 1 key to be pressed, then calls the ``` on_press ``` funciton where checkes for key pressed, ctrl+v are 2 keys. I need to continuously wait for keys to be pressed.

Comment: With the method you're using you could call a function when 'ctrl' is recognized, this function would then check if 'v' is pressed, if yes, it calls the function it should, bc Ctrl+V ist pressed.